# How to create custom control based on Property Type in the Model Class in MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am Creating MVC Web Application , I would like when define the Property as Bool like :

```
 public bool? Active { get; set; }
```

then in the view, the check box will be generated including that specific cssclass "form-check-input" and surrounded by Div as the following :

```
<div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="Active">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Active">
                Check me out
            </label>
</div>
```

at this situation later if I have multiple properties in the model with type Bool , this html should be generated automatically !
I have provided the type bool as an example !
is there any Hint or is there any example you can provide ?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a single checkbox with Mvc Core you just use input-tag-helper. You need to define a `Boolean` property on your Model (or PageModel in case you use Razor Pages) and after that just pass it to the asp-for attribute, as long as the property is not nullable:

```
public bool Active { get; set; }
```

and in your view:

```
<input asp-for="Active" />
```

As you already may know the property name passed to the asp-for attribute is used for the values of both the id and name attributes. The generated HTML will include two fields for the `Active` property:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Active field is  required." id="Active" name="Active" value="true">
<input name="Active" type="hidden" value="false">
```

But if you want to generate multiple checkboxes then maybe you can start from this piece of code:

```
@for (var i = 1; Model.[your model].Count(); i++)
{
    <input asp-for="[your model][i].Active" />
}
```

Note `[your model]` is the name of your class model or PageModel if you use Razor Pages.

Comment: Thanks @Llazar , I know how to generate CheckBox from the model , but what really  I need : is how to surround the checkbox with DIV and define specific css class like 'form-check-input', for the  Bool Property in the model (like : Active in my example above)  ,in other way I need to apply bootstrap Layout automatically whenever I define it through Class Model , please return back to the main thread , it has more clear explanation ! –